# Should a question be closed as off-topic if the problem was incorrect understanding of the problem?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Just now, I posted the question [C# regex can't find text with whitespace if input is escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271870), where I was quickly helped in the comments by another user in the comments. However, the problem turned out to be something else, a misunderstanding of how something (in this case the Regex methods) works.

Should questions like this be closed (as off-topic)?

Comment: Unless it's a typo, no. Misunderstanding stuff isn't a valid close reason.

Comment: Questioners routinely guess at the problem incorrectly, that's why they need help.  It is totally fine that the problem statement is wrong, high odds that somebody else made the same mistake.  It is the answer that needs to identify it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

*"Basic misunderstanding"* is not an existing close reason; but *"being resolved in a manner that would not be helpful for future readers"* is.

Even if not a typo, if the question and answer are based in a misconception, many times the Q&A ends up being useless for future visitors, since they come looking for solution to problem "A", when the possible answers to your question would actually deal with problem "B".

It depends a lot on the specifics of the question and the problem you faced. Many of these questions are better closed/deleted, whereas in other cases they can be edited into shape and salvaged. Some other times, the misunderstanding it's a common one or useful enough so the question is worth preserving.